# Align Recaptcha and Send button with text box in DIV using CSS only?

Tags: html, css

Im stuggling to align my send button and recaptcha with the end of my text box in a contact form in a responsive way? I have been messing about with this for a couple of days and just cannot get it to align. Here is my jsfiddle:
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Dtorr1981/52jjhn1v/2/)

My current css is:

```
/*custom css*/
#gkBottom6 {
    background-color:#4c90fe;   
}
#hdr-lay {
    background-color: #4c90fe;
}

#container {
    background-color: #4c90fe;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}


#left-column {
    float: left;
    background-color: #4c90fe;
    border: 1px;
    width: 65%;
    height:inherit;

}
#right-column {
    float: left;
    width: 35%;
    background-color: #4c90fe;
    display: block;
    height:inherit;
    color:#fff;
}
#left-column > h3 {
    color:#fff;
}
#right-column > h3 {
    color:#fff;
}

/*Button Styling on contact form*/
.gkContactForm .button-border {
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    color: #4c90fe;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 47px;
    margin: 18px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 32px;
    width: auto!important;
    clear:both;
}
.gkContactForm .button-border:active,
.gkContactForm .button-border:focus,
.gkContactForm .button-border:hover {
    background: #fec54d;
    border-color: #fec54d;
    color: #fff;
}
/*Input area*/
.gkContactForm p.gkcontact-fields {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 7% 0 0;
    width: 44%;
}
.gkContactForm p.gkcontact-textarea {
    float: right;
    margin: 0;
    width: 49%;
}
.gkContactForm input {
    border-color: #4c90fe;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.gkContactForm textarea {
    border-color: #4c90fe;
    height: 159px!important;
}
/*Recapcha*/
.gkContactForm #dynamic_recaptcha_1 {   
    float: right;
    margin-top:12px;
}
```

I just want these to stay aligned to the edge of the text input box. Any help would be most appreciated as i have been going round in circles with this one for a while.

Regards
Donna

Answer (score 0):

You have the containing element floated right, but in addition you need to float the wonky textarea itself:

```
.gkContactForm textarea{
    float:right;
}
```

From there you may want to give the #left-column some padding because they all align exactly to the other column now.